# Why do I get PKCS7 padding errors when using CryptoStream?

Tags: c#, encryption, mono

I'm trying to encrypt  a stream and decrypt it again. When encrypting, I store the salt and IV (8 and 16 bytes) first into the target stream. When decrypting, I get a padding error in the line where CopyTo() is called. The full source of the class can be found in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Krumelur/cae91b2a9668ee9322f3).

The relevant code snippet for encryption is:

```
// Set position to start of stream.
                encryptedOutStream.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // Store the salt in the output stream. The salt is not a secret. Salt is used to generate different keys for identical passwords.
                var keyInfo = GenerateKey (password);
                encryptedOutStream.Write (keyInfo.Salt, 0, keyInfo.Salt.Length);

                // Store the IV in the output stream. The IV is randomly generated if not set explicitly. It is not a secret and used to create 
                // different encrypted output for identical plaintext input when using CBC cipher mode.
                encryptedOutStream.Write (aesAlgo.IV, 0, aesAlgo.IV.Length);

                // Let the algorithm know our key.
                aesAlgo.Key = keyInfo.Key;

                // Get an encrypting ICryptoTransform interface from the algorithm.
                using(var cryptoTransform = aesAlgo.CreateEncryptor ())
                // Pump the input stream through a crypto stream wrapping a memory stream.
                using(var encryptionStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedOutStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    plainInStream.CopyTo (encryptionStream);
                }
```

and for decryption:

```
// Read the salt.
                byte[] salt = new byte[8];
                encryptedInStream.Read (salt, 0, 8);

                // Read the IV.
                byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                encryptedInStream.Read (iv, 0, 16);
                aesAlgo.IV = iv;

                // Generate the key from the password and the salt.
                var keyInfo = GenerateKey (password, salt);
                aesAlgo.Key = keyInfo.Key;

                // Get a decrypting ICryptoTransform interface from the algorithm.
                using(var cryptoTransform = aesAlgo.CreateDecryptor ())
                // Pump the input stream through a crypto stream wrapping a memory stream.
                using(var decryptionStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedInStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    decryptionStream.CopyTo (decryptedOutStream);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect an issue involving the `EncryptString` and `DecryptString` methods, specifically the lines:

```
 encryptedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedOutStream.ToArray());
```

and

```
 using (var encryptedInStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)))
```

Effectively, this code incorrectly attempts to use text encoding on ciphertext, which is binary data.  This will introduce errors when the binary data does not happen to be a legal UTF8 sequence, corrupting the ciphertext and introducing padding issues.  Instead, a binary encoding method needs to be used (most simply, base64).

To correct the issue, change the above lines to:

```
 // change line 281:
 //  encryptedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedOutStream.ToArray());
 // to:
 encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedOutStream.ToArray());

// change line 251:
//  using (var encryptedInStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)))
// to:
using (var encryptedInStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(s)))
```

With this change, the conversion appears to work.  A simple driver to encrypt and then decrypt the plaintext "payload" with the password "password" prints the desired output:

```
string password = "password";
SymmetricCrypto c = new SymmetricCrypto();
string ct = c.EncryptString("payload", password);
Console.WriteLine(ct); // prints sLSZfzVQGCoML29... (ciphertext will vary)
string dt = c.DecryptString(ct, password);
Console.WriteLine(dt); // prints "payload"
```

Comment: Good spotting! Yeah, I missed that.